# How to use push with sub-arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 arrays like:

```
var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];
var arr3 = [];

//When I want to add something into array then I use
arr1.push("text");
arr2.push("text");
```

but is it possible to make something like the following example?

```
//example:
var arr = [];

arr['group1'].push("text1");
arr['group2'].push("text2");
arr['group2'].push("textn");

//and then iterate like:

for(item in arr['group1'])
  console.log(item);
```

is it even possible to do something like that? I have tried but does not work.

Comment: An array object need to *exist* before it can have `push` invoked upon it .. `arr['group1']` evaluates to undefined in the code snipped above and `undefined.push("text1")` promptly complains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a fundamental misunderstanding though, `arr` is an array but you're using it as an associative array, which in JavaScript is better represented with an object `{}`. `for...in` is for objects, NOT arrays, the MDN has a warning note about it:

> `for..in` **should not be used to iterate over an Array where index order
>   is important**...

I would advice even if index is trivial to use a regular `for` loop or a `forEach`.

Consider using the following, more appropiate approach.

```
var obj = {
  group1: ['text1'],
  group2: ['text2'],
  group3: ['text3']
};

// pushing more strings
obj.group1.push('foo');
obj['group2'].push('baz');
```

Comment: +1 for, "for..in should not be used to iterate over an Array where index order is important.."

Answer (score 3):

You're treating `arr['group1']` as an array (by using `.push()`), but you haven't declared it as an array.

```
var arr = [];

arr['group1'] = [];
arr['group2'] = [];
arr['group3'] = [];

arr['group1'].push("text1");
arr['group2'].push("text2");
arr['group2'].push("textn");
```

Comment: `arr` should be a plain `Object`, rather than an `Array` as you're not using it as an array in any way.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're actually looking for Javascript Objects instead of arrays.
Also, you need to create these objects first.

```
var obj = {group1:[],group2:[],group3:[]};

/* or
var obj = {};
obj.group1 = [];
*/

obj['group1'].push("text1");
// or obj.group1.push("text1");
```

Comment: This is an perfect idea! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) structure sets your for variable to the key, not the value. Assuming `arr['group1']` is an array, this will work fine:

```
//example:
var arr = [];

arr['group1'].push("text1");
arr['group2'].push("text2");
arr['group2'].push("textn");

//and then iterate like:

for(item in arr['group1'])
  console.log(arr['group1'][item]);​
```

Comment: Check out the docs for `for...in` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in